# Column sum in matrix tables

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, matrix, reportviewer

I have a matrix table in Reportviewer and I'm trying to get sum of all data columns downwards.

I have written this expression:

```
=Sum(fields!Month.Value)
```

But when I run the report, in the total cells it's indicated as `"#Error"`.

So how to get the sum of columns as the last row in a matrix table?

Answer (score 0):

Right click `row` cell and go to `Add Totals` under `Tablix` and select `After`.

That sorted out the issue ;)